# ArgumentsError in RedshiftRecord call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-redshift

The code I've been working with is using RedshiftRecord to access a secondary database, and it works in my own machine, but when pushing to a production environment using Dokku, all calls to RedshiftRecord, even a simple

```
sql_statement = <<-SQL
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table
SQL
RedshiftRecord.connection.execute(sql_statement)
```

throw an

```
[web.1]: F, [...] FATAL -- : [...]   
[web.1]: [...] ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)):
```

Which is clearly strange as in that instance I am only passing a simple sql statement.
Both machines are using ruby 2.6.6 and rails 6.0.3.7, as well as this version of RedshiftRecord: https://github.com/iamdbc/activerecord6-redshift-adapter
I already made sure the environment variables, especially the database credentials were the same in both environments.

What could be the problem, what can I do to diagnose it, or what could I do to circumvent it?

Summary:
Tried making even a minimalist call to RedshiftRecord.
Expected the call to go through in both the production and development environments.
The call goes through in the development environment, but not production, even though environment variables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As is common, after a week of hair pulling I found the solution by myself five minutes after posting the question. While env variables were correct, variable *names* were wrong, and apparently, if you're missing a variable in Rails.application.secrets.redshift_config, you misleadingly get an ArgumentsError when calling it.